# Is it possible to provide a variable Enumerated Type as a parameter to a C# method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums, parameters

I apologise if this is a dumb question! I presently have several different methods to funnel selection into a generic Spawn method, called by different enumerated types to access different arrays of objects:

```
Prefab[] shipPrefabs;
Prefab[] rockPrefabs;
Prefab[] alienPrefabs;
Prefab[] shotPrefabs;

enum SHIP_TYPE{}
enum ROCK_TYPE{}
enum ALIEN_TYPE{}
enum SHOT_TYPE{}

void Spawn(SHIP_TYPE, ...) { Spawn(shipPrefabs[(int)SHIP_TYPE]); }
void Spawn(ROCK_TYPE, ...) { Spawn(rockPrefabs[(int)ROCK_TYPE]); }
void Spawn(ALIEN_TYPE, ...) { Spawn(alienPrefabs[(int)ALIEN_TYPE]); }
void Spawn(SHOT_TYPE, ...) { Spawn(shotPrefabs[(int)SHOT_TYPE]); }

void Spawn(Prefab) { create object, yada yada }
```

I'd like to be able to create a more generalised Spawn method that can take a variable enum parameter and process it accordingly based on enum type, something conceptually like:

```
void Spawn(var OBJ_TYPE, ...) {
    Prefab newObject;
    switch(OBJ_TYPE){
        case SHIP_TYPE: newObject = shipPrefabs[(int)OBJ_TYPE]);  break;
        case ROCK_TYPE: newObject = rockPrefabs[(int)OBJ_TYPE]);  break;
        case ALIEN_TYPE: newObject = alienPrefabs[(int)OBJ_TYPE]);  break;
        case SHOT_TYPE: newObject = shotPrefabs[(int)OBJ_TYPE]);  break;
    }

    create newObject, yada yada
}
```

I've tried things like 'typeof' and 'is' which tells me what the parameter is, but I can't 'cast' it into a value I can work with.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying?

Comment: Create an overload for each enum. if you have code that repeats in all overloads, consider taking out out to another private method.

Comment: It is possible, but not recommended. There are better ways - depending on the level of complexity I’d go for overloads (as suggested by @zohar) or separate classes for each type rather than an enumeration (a completely different way of working, but tends to be easier when the project gets large)

Comment: @ZoharPeled looks like OP already **has** an overload for each enum ...

Comment: @derHugo yes. still this is the c# way of doing what the OP wants....

Comment: @teambanana - Why is it not recommended and the overloaded method which I already have preferred?

Comment: @DavidCoombes because it kind of breaks with the hard typing in `c#`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general I would rather keep your first approach of using an overloaded method and do not invent ways around the hard typing in `c#`.

Runtime type checks are always slower and error prone.

---

However, using a type switch you can totally do what you tried just with a few modifications.

The generic `enum` type you were looking for is [`System.Enum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.enum)

```
void Spawn(Enum OBJ_TYPE, ...) 
{
    Prefab newObject = null;

    switch(OBJ_TYPE)
    {
        // This also directly includes the type cast
        case SHIP_TYPE shipType: 
            newObject = shipPrefabs[(int) shipType]);  
            break;

        case ROCK_TYPE rockType: 
            newObject = rockPrefabs[(int)rockType]); 
            break;

        case ALIEN_TYPE alienType: 
            newObject = alienPrefabs[(int) alienType]); 
            break;

        case SHOT_TYPE shotType: 
            newObject = shotPrefabs[(int) shotType]); 
            break;

        default:
            throw new ArgumentException($"Enum {OBJ_TYPE} of unsupported type {OBJ_TYPE.GetType().FullName} ");
    }

    // create newObject, yada yada
}
```

The included type cast to the according `enum` is probably even redundant if you don't do anything further with it since you then cast to `int` anyway which should be the same value as simply directly using `(int)OBJ_TYPE`

*NOTE though*: As said on the top of the answer, this can now possibly be used with just **any** `enum` value which is of course a lot more error prone then using overloads.

Comment: Perfect. Now I just need to know if this is actually the best approach or it was a dumb question after all!

Comment: @DavidCoombes *best* depends on your use case ... In my eyes better would be using proper dictionaries instead of arrays ;) But then again: Unity by default doesn't support Serialization of dictionaries. But again .. there are assets that do so personally I would use e.g. [Serializable dictionary](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.core@8.2/api/UnityEngine.Rendering.SerializedDictionary-2.html)

Comment: Or just stick to the overloads as they are hard typed which is way cleaner then runtime type checks

Comment: Or just stick to the overloads as they are hard typed which is way cleaner then runtime type checks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
void Spawn(System.Enum otype, ...) {
    Prefab newObject;
    if (otype.GetType() == typeof(SHIP_TYPE))
        newObject = shipPrefabs[(int)otype]);
    else if (otype.GetType() == typeof(ROCK_TYPE))
        newObject = rockPrefabs[(int)otype]);
    else if (otype.GetType() == typeof(ALIEN_TYPE))
        newObject = alienPrefabs[(int)otype]);
    else if (otype.GetType() == typeof(SHOT_TYPE))
        newObject = shotPrefabs[(int)otype]);

    create newObject, yada yada
}
```

One thing, you can not use switch for this, as it does not see typeof as constant. I am not sure you can overcome this.

Whether it is a good design approach or not is another question.

Comment: Btw your `break;` make no sense ;)

Comment: Think he just copy/pasted my lines. ;)

Answer (score 0):

As nested enums are not permitted, a cool way using multiple enums and overloading can be this:

```
        GameObject[] shipPrefabs;
        GameObject[] rockPrefabs;
        GameObject[] alienPrefabs;
        GameObject[] shotPrefabs;

        GameObject[][] goArray = new GameObject[][] {
            new GameObject[4],
            new GameObject[4],
            new GameObject[4],
            new GameObject[4],
        };

        private void Start() {
            goArray[0] = shipPrefabs;
            goArray[1] = rockPrefabs;
            goArray[2] = alienPrefabs;
            goArray[3] = shotPrefabs;
        }

        enum ObjType {
            SHIP_TYPE,
            ROCK_TYPE,
            ALIEN_TYPE,
            SHOT_TYPE,
        }

        enum ShipType { 
            a, b, c, d
        }
        enum RockType {
            e, f, g, h
        }
        enum AlienType {
            i, j, k, m
        }
        enum ShotType {
            n, o, p, q
        }

        void Spawn(GameObject go) { }

        void Spawn(ObjType objType, ShipType shipType) {
            Spawn(goArray[(int)objType][(int)shipType]);
        }
        void Spawn(ObjType objType, RockType rockType) {
            Spawn(goArray[(int)objType][(int)rockType]);
        }
        void Spawn(ObjType objType, AlienType alienType) {
            Spawn(goArray[(int)objType][(int)alienType]);
        }
        void Spawn(ObjType objType, ShotType shotType) {
            Spawn(goArray[(int)objType][(int)shotType]);
        }
```